# Java Applet requests /META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory

Tags: java, applet, meta-inf

I have a signed java applet that runs on a web page and every time it loads, it requests the following files on the host:

- GET /META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
- GET /META-INF/services/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager

The server returns a HTTP 404 for each of them and it has no impact on the applet functionality.

Why does the applet request these files and how can i disable those requests?

Thanks,
Joel